# A wrong counterexample for the Sequential Compactness Theorem for general metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Example 12.38 from the book Advanced Calculus by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick is trying to say that the assertion "sequentially compact if and only if X is a closed bounded" does not necessarily hold for all metric spaces.

The counterexample is the subset of $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ consisting of all continuous  functions such that $|f(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. It then claims that this subset is closed and gives the sequence of functions $f_k(x)=x^k$ as a counterexample for the subset not to sequentially compact.

But the problem is that this subset is not closed because the same sequence of functions $f_k(x)=x^k$ converges to the function that satisfy $|f(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ but it is not in $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ contradiction to the definition of closedness of a set. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not right. In the metric $d(f,g) = \sup \{|f(x) - g(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$ that is used on this space $X= C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, the sequence $f_k$ does not converge at all. So it cannot be a counterexample to closedness of the set $C= \{f: \forall x: |f(x)| \le 1\}$, because then there has to be a function $f \in X$ (!) such that $f_k \to f$ with $f_k \in C$ for all $k$ and $f \notin C$, because we are talking about closed sets in $(X,d)$.

Suppose $f_k$ did converge to some $f \in X$. Then it has to converge pointwise to $f$ too, as $|f_k(x) - f(x)| \le d(f_k,f) \to 0$ for any fixed $x \in [0,1]$, and this forces $f(0) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(1) = 1$, which contradicts the continuity of $f$.

$C$ is bounded by definition, as it is just the closed ball of radius $1$ around
the $0$-function, it is closed too: suppose $g \notin C$, then there is some $p \in [0,1]$ with $|f(p)| > 1$. Then it's easy to check that, setting $r = 1-|f(p)| >0$, $B_d(g,r) \cap C =\emptyset$.

The fact that no subsequence of $(f_k)$ converges (the argument I gave also works for any subsequence) shows that $C$ is not (sequentially ) compact, as claimed.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. The given counterexample is not true. That is the Example's reasoning is not true.

Comment: @Edi the example **is** true.

Comment: Then how "the subset of $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ consisting of all continuous  functions such that $|f(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$" is closed? Obviously ${\{f_k(x)=x^k}\}$ does not converge to a point in the set as the limit function is not continuous so the set is not closed.

Comment: @Edi I added an argument why it's closed. I explained why the sequence is no counterexample to closedness. E.g. $(0,1]$ is not closed in the real line, because of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ which **does** converge in the real line (this is essential) but whose limit does not lie in the set $(0,1]$ even though the whole sequence *is* in the set. The $f_k$ do not converge in $X$, so they don't count to refute closedness of $C$ in $X$.

Comment: So more exact definition of closedness is that : first of all for closedness we first need to specify an embedding/super-set; then we say if any sequence which converges in the set and if whole sequence lies in the subset and if the limit is in the subset so, that subset is closed in the set. Am I right?

Comment: @Edi Exactly. We are always talking about a set being closed in a space, so the space is the context in which things have to converge. In this case $X = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. When you say "the sequence of $x^k$ converges to something" what topology do you mean? You certainly do not mean uniform convergence (in sup-norm), because the sequence $x^k$ is not Cauchy sequence in sup-norm. Do you mean the point-wise (weak) convergence? When the author says that the unit ball is closed, he means the original (normed/strong) topology. In this topology, the unit ball is closed because any sequence of functions that converges *uniformly* will have the limit to be a continuous function with the norm being bounded by one (norm is continuous in the original topology). A sequence cannot converge to something outside the space if the space is complete ($C[0,1]$ with the sup-norm is).